# Strange distortion and low performance using cycles viewport renderer in Blender 3.0 and onwards

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, artifacts

[image: Pixels become triangular and low res when using cycles viewport renderer]

[image: Viewport renderer works as expected when looking through the camera]

Essentially the problem is when in viewport render mode with cycles, if I'm not looking through the camera, objects become incredibly distorted as shown in the first picture. NumPad 0 to align view with the camera solves it but only when looking through the camera.

In addition to the massive distortion and pixelation, viewport rendering and even camera movements become incredibly slow and unresponsive. I only noticed this after the 3.0 update, but don't believe it happened instantly after the update. I'm simply unsure what I could have done to cause this.

Comment: Maybe a driver upgrade, or somehow force the render kernel cache to rebuild

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Viewport Pixel Size, here.

[image]